# Estimating TCP and UDP delay between two nodes

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, delay

Suppose we have 2 nodes, A and B, directly connected by Internet (we can ignore the underlyng network eg, routers, ISP etc).

We know **RTT** between nodes (80ms)

We know **packet loss** (0.1)

We know **jitter** (1ms)

We know **bandwith**, A=100/10mbps B=50/5mbps (first value is download, second is upload)

A sends a 1GB file to B by using the TCP protocol (with 64KB segment size).

- How many times they need to exchange the file?
- How many times it takes to do the same thing by using the UDP
  protocol?

EDIT:
i guess the main difference in the calculation between UDP and TCP is that in TCP we need to wait for every packet to be sent before sending the next one. Or, in other words, we have to add in the delay calculation one RTT for every packet. Moreover, packetloss is not considered at all in UDP. I am not sure of what I'm sayng in this edit, so let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: "_in TCP we need to wait for every packet to be sent before sending the next one. Or, in other words, we have to add in the delay calculation one RTT for every packet._" That is not actually true. TCP has windows for the amount of data that can be sent before an acknowledgement is required, and it can be much larger than one segment.

Comment: @RonMaupin This was very usefull, thank you!